# Change android theme using preference and Configuration

Tags: android, android-theme

I am trying to implement android theme (using `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight">`).

Now, from `SettingActivity`, I am truing to choose theme.
I have defined `SettingsActivity` as:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.settings_activity);
    getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.settings, new SettingsFragment())
        .commit();
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
      actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
  }

  public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {
    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
      setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.root_preferences, rootKey);
    }
  }
}
```

and `res/xml/root_preferences` has:

```
    <ListPreference
        app:defaultValue="default"
        app:entries="@array/themes_labels"
        app:entryValues="@array/themes_color"
        app:key="Theme"
        app:title="@string/Theme"
        app:useSimpleSummaryProvider="true" />
  </PreferenceCategory>
```

where the arrays are defined as:

```
 <array name="themes_labels">
    <item>"Default"</item>
    <item>"Light"</item>
    <item>"Dark"</item>
  </array>

  <string-array name="themes_color">
    <item>"Default"</item>
    <item>"Light"</item>
    <item>"Dark"</item>
  </string-array>
```

Now, problem is how to implement the theme, i.e. getting the values from preference and implement. [This](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/darktheme) guide shows a very easy way as:

```
int currentNightMode = configuration.uiMode & Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK;
switch (currentNightMode) {
    case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO:
        // Night mode is not active, we're using the light theme
        break;
    case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES:
        // Night mode is active, we're using dark theme
        break;
}
```

But the question is how I can get the value of ListPreference and put it to `uiMode`.

Kindly help.

Comment: I don't understand your question fully, please clear something - Are you asking user to set a theme or You want your App to change theme according device's Night-Mode?

Comment: I am asking user to set a theme, as given in the `theme_levels` array.

Comment: Are you saving selected theme in `SharedPreferences` and checking and setting it before `setContentView()`?

Comment: No, the quoted text is all I have done.

Comment: Actually I realise that I have to save the selection somewhere, but with my limited java knowledge, don't know how to do that.

Comment: Save user selected theme in `SharedPreferences` and on every activity check which theme user have selected before `setContentView()` and user `setTheme()` to set theme before `setContentView()`. if you need more explanation please tell me I will post an answer

Comment: It will be nice if you kindly post an answer

Answer (score 2):

For saving theme use [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences),

To save data

```js
//init sharedPreferences
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("myPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.apply();

//for saving String
editor.putString("theme", "day"); // here "theme" is key and "day" is value
editor.apply();
```

now you can get saved theme like this

```js
//init SharedPreference here

//get SharedPreference
String sTheme = sharedPreferences.getString("theme", ""); // "theme" is key and second "" is default value

// now according to this value change theme
switch(sTheme){
    // check and set theme here
    setTheme(R.style.NightTheme);

}
// this is before setContent

setContentView(R.layout.your_activity);
```

You can create static method to do all this as you have to check and set theme in every `activity`

You also need to create multiple `Style` in `res->styles.xml`

Hope this will help!

Comment: thanks for your answer. But I still does not get it. The problem is, in my `ListPreference` layout, I have three values(i.e. Default, Dark and Ligh) as an array. So, when user is choosing a value I have to save that as `SharedPreference`. How I can apply that then using `Configuration.uiMode`?

Comment: `Configuration.uiMode` this is use to get System theme, if the OS is on NightMode or DayMode

Comment: This solved my problem, I just replaced setTheme with AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode